# WPF data template dynamic switching

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a class that represents an asynchronous result. There will be an exposed boolean dependency property called "IsCalculating". If that value is true, I want the visualiser to show template A - which will be a "now processing..." image. When the processing completes asynchronously on a background thread, it will update that property to False, at which point I want the WPF visualiser to automatically be notified and switch to template B, which will display the finished results.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Does not switch out templates but PriorityBinding might work if you can get you final template to present a "now processing" message.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  The simplest option is potentially to just use a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) to toggle the visibility of both "templates" as needed.  However, there are other options, such as using the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx) to designate separate states (as well as how to transition between them).